# CMAKE Parallel Build issue

Tags: cmake

I have external Project which is make based, I am able to compile link successfully. ( I have modified make infra of third party project to break large make into multiple smaller makes so that parallelly different small make can run, but it is orthogonal to this question)

Third party cmake  is as below

```
External_Project_Add( ...
             ....
             #NO BUILD_COMMAND)
```

But Compilation is too slow, and I can see that max number of compilation doesn't exceed 8 threads and CPU utilization is ~20%.  (we are using distcc as well). 
If I change as below

```
External_Project_Add( ...
             ....
         BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build <dir> --parallel --)
```

Compilation is super-fast by atleast 3 time. However occasionally system run out of PIDs.

Is there way to control max number of PIDs/process    available to CMAKE ?

I had thought about using -j option is BUILD_COMMAND but it is artificially going to reduce the compilation compute available to my system.

I have tried changing $(MAKE) in my third party make to have -jn, but then it shows jobserver domain warning. It is not good idea to change third party make as well. So I dropped this idea.

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: If you don't specify `BUILD_COMMAND`, then `ExternalProject_Add` will automatically use `$(MAKE)` if it finds that current generator is "Makefiles", see code of [ExternalProject.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/c58f5e116e0fd4fd883320812bfb052582005e90/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake#L1822). If you want to provide `BUILD_COMMAND` by yourself, then you need conditionally adjust the command according to the generator. [CMake developers said](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16273#note_158909) that `cmake --build` doesn't act as *jobserver* for cooperate with `make -j`

Comment: Thanks, I am Specifying BUILD_COMMAND only for "Parallel" aka Fast compilation. Otherwise I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cmake --build . --help
Unknown argument --help
Usage: cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
Options:
  -j [<jobs>] --parallel [<jobs>] = Build in parallel using
                   the given number of jobs. If <jobs> is omitted
                   the native build tool's default number is used.
                   The CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL environment variable
                   specifies a default parallel level when this option
                   is not given.
```

`cmake` passes the `-j` and `-j <jobs>` request to the build tool.  `cmake --build` will run the appropriate build tool depending on the generator used and will add the correct options to run a parallel build.  So just use `-j <jobs>` to limit the max number of requested jobs.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try this up, However in my system